# Adding HTML popup in exported PDF map?

Tags: arcpy, export, popup, pdf, html

I am producing some maps of a point layer using arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF. Is there a possibility of creating HTML popup for the final PDF based on this link?

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Using_HTML_pop_ups_for_feature_layers/00s500000018000000/